# Unable to reinstall vlc

Tags: apt, software-installation, vlc, aptitude

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS x86_64

I was trying to download and compile VLC ...

During that process I have broken already installed vlc

Reinstalling does not help.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
apt remove --purge  vlc*
apt install vlc
```

Nothing, still when I type which vlc in applications I get nothing, only folder displays

Also I have tried

```
aptitude install vlc
```

Nothing after that as well...

Tried adding sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/vlc and then installing also nothing whatever I do I just get command line vlc 3.0.12

However when I check logs it says:

```
Unpacking vlc-bin (3.0.18-0build5~ubuntu2004) over (3.0.18-0build5~ubuntu2004) ...
Setting up vlc-bin (3.0.18-0build5~ubuntu2004) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
```

And when I type vlc in command line I get 3.0.12...

I can't run GUI no matter what I try...

I don't want to use snap....

I have even upgraded to 22.04

And I still get:
VLC media player 3.0.12 Vetinari (revision 3.0.12-1-0-gd147bb5e7e)

Comment: I have even tried add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/master-daily -y it's vlc 4, but after installation it again says 3.0.12 ...

Comment: "Nothing, still when I type which vlc in applications I get nothing, only folder displays" What do you mean by "folder displays"?

Comment: You have to first remove the compiled version. APT cannot do that since you did not install the compiled version with apt. How exactly did you install it? Add all the steps

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi if I delete /usr/bin/vlc and reinstall with newer version, again old version pops-up

Comment: @RA I mean "Show Applications" from the dock/panel.

Comment: Add the output of `which vlc` command

Comment: @RA I was deleting it multiple times... /usr/bin/vlc even if I download new VLC and overwrite the one in /usr/bin/vlc it stil says vlc 3.0.12

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I was able to uninstall but only by following this:

1. I've downloaded exactly the same version that I have compiled:

   axel -a -n 4 http://ftp.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/3.0.12/vlc-3.0.12.tar.xz
2. Boostrapped and configured it

   cd vlc-3.0.12
   ./bootstrap
   ./configure --disable-alsa --disable-live555 --disable-chromecast
3. Uninstalled

   sudo make uninstall